# TokenMismatchException RANDOM on ajax requests Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, csrf

How this can be explained?

1. Clean install Laravel
2. Using redis for session and cache
3. The problem occur only if I start the server on windows and only shows on Chrome.
4. Using a simple js function for ajax call:

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       },
       data: {
           _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });

   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

       getUsers();
   }

   function getUsers() {
       $.ajax({
           url: '/users',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
       });
   }
   ```
5. Setting CSRF in meta `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`
6. Returning a JSON with data:

   public function users() {

   ```
   $users = User::all();

   return response()->json([
       'users' => $users,
   ]);
   ```

   }
7. At the final of the video you can see RANDOM TokenMismatchException even the token never change but sometime error occur.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDucHoP647g

I know this problem has been discussed from years but why does not exist a solution for this?

I also posted on laravel github but none of solutions did not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you send the token twice? remove that data part from `$.ajaxSetup()`

And why are you using POST for getting users? use GET instead.

Comment: This is an example. Assuming I will make an insert on that POST /users. The error will occur. From my tests I just found that the problem TokenMismatchException occur only if I click remember me . (and I removed one of the token and send it once).

Comment: This is no actually an answer to the author's question.